# I want to label all the intersection points of the x-axis and y-axis with numbers in Highcharts radar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTOdk.png)
like picture

make up the number of words.make up the number of words.make up the number of words.make up the number of words.make up the number of words.make up the number of words.make up the number of words.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve that will be by using extra yAxes.

Based on the following code example, define your yAxis and add additional axes that will be linked to them. Define the angle of each new axis as well.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    polar: true,
  },
  yAxis: [{
    tickInterval: 2,
    min: 0,
    max: 6,
  }, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    angle: 46,
  }, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    angle: 90,
  }],

  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3n4c8msg/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.angle

---

EDIT:

In the case of the "spider" polar, it will be necessary to set the  `gridLineWidth: 0` for each additional axis.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5dno4fyk/

Comment: However, the customer's requirement is a spider chart, and it looks strange after changing it to a spider chart. Can you help me modify it?
demo:https://jsfiddle.net/qqqqqqqqq/x9r2t4wk/5/

Comment: Apologize for the oversight. I edited my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c4anr2zb/
```

x-Axis and y-Axis options are defined with the tickInterval set to 1.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      polar: true,
      type: 'line'
    },
    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 1,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value.toString();
        }
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      tickInterval: 1,
      labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return this.value.toString();
        }
      }
    },

  });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my brother, my English isn't very good. Let me rephrase my request: In the graph, all the intersection points on the x-axis and y-axis are labeled with numbers, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and so on.